# Discord.js/Firestore .where() is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, discord.js

I am trying to integrate my discord bot with firestore. Whenever I try to run a query I get .where is not a function and I don't understand why because everything else seems to work. Here is the relevant code. I have tried the require of firebase at the top of Remove.js and that doesn't seem to do anything.
Here is my thought to how I believe it should be working right now.

1. I run node . and it then runs my index.js file.
2. On an interaction create (i.e. a slash command is created) it checks the command file and in this case it is the remove command
3. It calls execute(interaction, db) where interaction is the interaction slash command and db is the admin.Firestore() db reference from index.js. I am fully able to use get commands (i.e. that first chunk of code works before I try to delete)
4. Because this is a reference I should be able to call .where() based on the Firestore documentation and yet I am hit with the error "TypeError: db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc(...).where is not a function"

---

```
// Index.js
    // General Setup
    const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js')
    const config = require('./config.json')
    const fs = require('fs')
    
    // Bot Setup
    const myIntents = new Intents();
    myIntents.add(Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS)
    const bot = new Client({intents: myIntents});
    
    // Firebase Setup
    const firebase = require('firebase/app')
    const fieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue
    const admin = require('firebase-admin')
    const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json')
    
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
    })
    
    let db = admin.firestore();
    
    // Command Setup
    bot.commands = new Collection();
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
    
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        bot.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    }
    
    // Bot Login
    bot.once('ready', async () => {
        console.log('Wheatley is online!');
    });
    
    bot.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) {
            return
        }
    
        const command = bot.commands.get(interaction.commandName)
    
        if (!command) {
            return
        }
    
        try {
            await command.execute(interaction, db)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true})
        }
    });
    
    bot.login(config.bot_token);
```

```
    ///Remove.js
    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
    require('@firebase/firestore');
    
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName('remove')
            .setDescription('Removes object from collection')
            .addStringOption(option => 
                option.setName('item')
                .setDescription('Enter an item in the collection to remove')
                .setRequired(true)
            ),
        async execute(interaction, db) {
            const itemName = await interaction.options.getString('item')
            const itemToDelete = db.collection('items').doc(interaction.guildId).collection('items').doc(itemName);
            const doc = await itemToDelete.get();
            if(!doc.exists) {
                return interaction.reply({
                    content: `${itemName} does not exist in the collection. Try using /list to check for the right name.`,
                    ephemeral: true
                })
            }
            
            const ownerId = interaction.user.id
            const snapshot = db.collection('items').doc(interaction.guildId).collection('items').doc(itemName).where("ownerId", "==", ownerId).get();
            if(!snapshot.exists) {
                return interaction.reply({
                    content: `You are not the owner of ${itemName}. Please contact owner to delete this from the collection`,
                    ephemeral: true
                })
            }
            itemToDelete.delete();
            return await interaction.reply(`${itemName} was removed from the collection!`)
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `where` on a document, as `where` is a query function that is only available to collections.
Just be warned that the snapshot will return an array of snapshots as it is a query, not a single document.

Try this instead:

```js
const snapshot = db.collection('items').doc(interaction.guildId).collection('items').where("ownerId", "==", ownerId).get();
```